# Import error in python, when modules have imports

Tags: python-3.x, import

I have this problem with python, and I'm absolutely lost, I hope that some of you know a solution. Considering the project structure

```
main_folder
main.py
----second_folder
----a.py
----b.py
```

in `main.py`

```py
import second_folder.a as bla
```

in `a.py`

```py
import b as blub
```

When I run `a.py` everything works fine, but when I run `main.py` I get the error `No module named 'b'`.
I tried literally everything, but I don't see a "clean" solution for this problem.

I know, this might be a duplicate, but I'm searching for weeks, and I'm really frustrated at this point :( I think python is a really cool language, but this problem makes it nearly unusable for large projects.

Comment: In `main.py` your import statement is fine.  But in `a.py` it needs to be namespaced:  `import second_folder.b as blub`.

Comment: Maybe try adding an empty `__init__.py` file to second_folder?

Comment: @wim I also tried that but then, I cannot run `a.py` gives me an import error, and I need to run `a.py` on it's own.

Comment: @purple also tried that, without any success :(

Comment: What about `from second_folder import a as bla`?

Comment: @purple same :( `No module named 'second_folder'`

Comment: You still have the empty `__init__` in second_folder correct?

Comment: @purple yes I have

Comment: From within the "main_folder", you could run `a.py` with the following command `python -m second_folder.a`.  You can not run `a.py` directly as a script, since it needs to import from a "sibling" module and that is only supported from within a package, it's not supported for standalone scripts.

Comment: @wim but this problem keeps propagating, even if I add my upper scenario as a subrepo and import main.py as a module.